# Krea Content Elements Field and EE 2.6.1 Relationships Field - how to use parts of an article in the related articles section of a Single Entry Page

Tags: custom-fields, relationships, related-entries

On our web-site each article (Single Entry Page) is accompanied by 4 related articles. Those 4 are chosen by the editors. I set up a native EE 2.6.1 Relationships Field for them.
For the article itself I set up a Content Elements Field.
In the related articles are below the main article I´d like to show

1. the title of the related articles
2. the articles first image (called intro_image)
3. I also need the url_title_path, to make title + image clickable.

I have no problems with title + url, but can´t get the CE tag to work.

This is my code

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="article" status="open|featured"}
       {related_article status="not closed"}
          {artikel}
            {gallery}
              {if element_name=="intro_image"}
                 {images}
                    {related_article:image} <= doesn´t work!
                 {images}
              {/if}
            {/gallery}
          {/artikel}
          <p><a href="{related_article:url_title_path='artikel/index'}">
{related_article:title}</a></p>
      {/related_article}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

This code is working fine for the title and the URL, but not for the image. I tried to prefix `{artikel}`, `{gallery}`, `{image}` in various combination with `{related_article:}`. But this is not working. When I leave out the related_article in frot of each of the three tags, I get the intro image from the main article. So I need an identifier, that points to the child entry.

Answer (score 1):

First off, your `{images}` tag is duplicated - instead of closing the first tag with `{/images}`, you have another `{images}`. Dunno if that's a simple typo from simplifying the actual template or not.

Secondly, is the `{if element_name=="intro_image"}` code getting called at all? I've found that such conditionals never work for me. I have to wrap `element_name` in quotes and EE tags: `{if '{element_name}' == "intro_image"}`. You can insert some temporary code in the conditional to make sure that part is working at least:

```
          {if '{element_name}'=="intro_image"}
             {!-- Debug code --}
             Element name is "intro_image"!
             {!-- // Debug code --}
             {images}
                {related_article:image} <= doesn´t work!
             {images}
             --}
          {/if}
```

Once all that's sorted out, if you still have problems, let me know. :)

EDIT: And yes, I know this is a rather old question, but Google sent me here! :p